# Realtime antivirus software for Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, anti-virus, realtime

Microsoft's Forefront Client Security doesn't install on Windows Server 2008 R2. I'm talking specifically about FCS without update server that updates via Windows Update:

```
clientsetup /nomom
```

This installation doesn't work on a server operating system. Hence the question.

So the question is: Which realtime antivirus is *Windows Server 2008 **R2*** installable?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? Obviously, you got a virus. Was it through e-mail? Was it a worm? A server exploit (in which case it wasn't a virus but a hacker)? You say you're running a server, but does anyone ever sit at it and use it "manually"? Do you know what virus it was?

Comment: It's worth noting that every antivirus solution has a period between virus creation and virus discovery and software update during which you can get infected. There's no such thing as a perfect antivirus product.

Comment: the key word in the question is "realtime" I guess, that is the ability to check files "on the fly", or, phrasing it in yet another way, check all files in the background as soon as they are created or modified. This sometimes is called file system hooks. In this sense, this question is perfectly valid

Comment: I've just setup the system and am using it as a power workstation. So there's a person behind it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We like NOD32 http://www.eset.com/
has a centralized management console, push installation and global rules that can be configured from a admin location.

Comment: Yes but it can't be installed on a server OS can it? At least not the antivirus.

Comment: Well I found out that NOD32 Antivirus Business Edition DOES install on a server. I'm now using it for some time and I'm really happy with it.

Comment: Though the System Requirements for NOD32 Antivirus Business Edition doesn't state that 2008 R2 is supported?

Comment: NOD32* works great on Server 2008 R2. (* yes, the 64-bit version is still called NOD32)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is exceptionally poorly phrased. "Doesn't work" tells us nothing. Is there an installation problem? Is it giving run-time errors? Is it that a virus got through?

To Channel the IT crowd "Please state the precise nature of the problem".

Assuming the issue is that a virus got through - that can always happen. No AV is perfect because they can only detect known threats. Those threats only become "known" AFTER they have infected machines. They are purely re-active, so they can never be perfect.

Also, there are technique attackers use to disguise even known malware through "packing", so even known threats can be disguised to get through AV.

There is no silver bullet.

Sorry.

Comment: I'm sorry. I clarified my question now. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Cool, that much better and much clearer now. Unfortunately, I don't have an answer for you now that I know what you're looking for. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Newer versions of Forefront Client Security will install on Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.  I just finished an install today of a standalone, get-updates-from-Windows-Update installation of Forefront Client Security on W2008 R2 and it worked fine.

Note that you'll need to run the `clientsetup /nomom` in the `\CLIENT\x64\` directory of the installation media. The `clientsetup.exe` in the `\CLIENT\` folder won't install on a 64-bit OS.

Answer (score 0):

We're pretty happy with the offerings from [F-Secure](http://www.f-secure.com/en_US/products/business/servers/anti-virus-for-servers/index.html).  We use it on workstations, servers and mobiles.

Comment: Scratching my head on why this was downvoted. If one hasn't had good experiences with F-Secure, why begrudge someone who has?

Comment: I was wondering as well.  Out of all the commercial products we've tried, we've had the best luck with F-Secure on many levels, but of course your mileage may vary.  Every product out there will have problem environments, it's just the nature of the beast.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all make sure not to go to suspicious websites. install mcafee and update it EVERY 12 hours!

Comment: In fact, don't go to any websites. It's a server.

Comment: Firewall, anyone?

Comment: I'm sorry, but McAfee is the one of the most bloated crap-ware there is (Only Norton is worse).

Comment: McAfee VSE has improved significantly since 8.7i was released. They have also released a management console for EPO to start weening people away from the clunky web interface.

Comment: @Ernie, What is a firewall going to prevent in the case of browsing suspect websites as an admin on a server? (note: if you actually do that, you probably deserve whatever you get, just hope you're not running as domain admin)

Answer (score 0):

If you're specifying Windows Update - that's only going to distribute to *Microsoft* products.  Ruling out MS AV makes this a self-canceling question, unfortunately.

My humble suggestion would be that if you need 2008 server on your workstation, do your web browsing from within a virtual, where you can install a *client* OS - which will be supported by a huge array of AV clients.  Fitting a square peg into a round hole doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: I'm not specifiying it has to update itself via Windows Update. Only FCS does that. I'm looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a real shortage of released products that work with 2008 R2 at the moment, but Kaspersky has a release candidate available of their Kaspersky Antivirus 6.0 MP4 product, release notes [here](http://www.kaspersky.com/downloads/pdf/products_overview.pdf) stating Windows 7 and Windows 2008 R2 support. You can grab a version for testing.

Comment: Indeed they released MP4 of Kaspersky Anti-Virus for Windows Servers a while back, seems to work well with 2008 and 2008 R2:

More info : http://www.kaspersky.co.uk/anti-virus_windows_server

Answer (score 0):

Clamwin works on Server 2008 R2 Enterprise